DDR5 ECC ram compatibility with ASRock motherboard
I'm going to build an home server to host games and services and I'm looking into the new AMD EPYC 4004 series processors. 
The motherboard I need to use is the AM5D4ID-2T/BCM which is the only mini-ITX (formerly "deep" mini-ITX, just a little longer) motherboard available right now supporting these new CPUs. 
Here comes the problem:
in the 'Memory QVL' section of the motherboard specification there are listed ECC and non-ECC modules, but the only DDR5 48GB (I absolutely need this size) ECC module listed here is from SMART and actually isn't available for purchase;
so the other options here are

using non-ECC modules, which I don't want to, since I'm building a server
trying different DDR5 48GB ECC modules that aren't listed in the compatibilty list

For this second point I'm asking questions: 
Crucial is doing DDR5 48GB ECC also, but ASRock didn't list it in the list. 
Can anyone tell me if these ram modules are gonna work if I put them in the motherboard? 
Is there a lot of difference from picking up 4800 MT/s vs 5600 MT/s? 
Don't know why, but on the Crucial website the faster one is cheaper, however I think 4800 MT/s is better since this speed is also the one registered from ASRock. 

The QVL only contains modules that ASRock tested, the absence of a specific module, doesn’t preclude compatibility. At the end of the day DDR5 is DDR5 the only compatible specifications you should be worried about should be operating frequency, density, and perhaps timing.

@Ramhound Ok, thanks!

The SMART are UDIMM (unregistered/unbuffered) ECC modules, the Crucial ones are RDIMM (registered/buffered). A quick glance on the motherboard's product page also states it takes UDIMM only.

On some motherboards as density increases frequency of the module might be more important. Taking the QVL has a guide will guarantee buying a compatible module even if that module has isn’t on the list. Pay attention to RDIMM and ECC compatibility. You are trying to compare UDIMM ECC memory to RDIMM ECC. If you do that you won’t be successful

@Silbee Oh ok, good to know! So this is the info that matters them most, the modules must be UDIMM

@Ramhound Yeah yeah, got it. Thanks.

@martinotecco well no, all information is important :) So you're looking for 48GB DDR5 4800MT/S UDIMM ECC ram. They are less easy to find. You're going to find alot of 48GB ECC RDIMM and even more 48GB non-ECC UDIMM (every normal non ecc stick is UDIMM basicly). Find yourself a retailer with a good return policy in case they turn out not to be compatible ! (especially since the 4004 is a new SKU).

As far as I know, Kingston KSM56E46BD8KM-48HM would be the part you're looking for and it is on QVL list for EPYC 4004 processors on some motherboards. I've been looking for different AM5 motherboard options, too, with target of going 4x48GB EEC DDR5 but the QVL lists seem to provide zero options. I think I would use 9950X instead of EPYC, though. EPYC 4584PX seems like a pretty similar part, though.
